# How to get the splicing regions (BED) of all genes for Human GRCh38?

Tags: bed, human

How can I obtain a BED file that describes the splicing sites of all genes for GRCh38 human genome ?

Thank you

Comment: Interested to know if there are special file format for RNAsplicing.

Comment: Is it the alternative splicing events you are looking for? https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/data/annotation/manuals/alternativeSplicingEvents.hg38/man/alternativeSplicingEvents.hg38.pdf

Comment: @PaulEndymion thanks for the link. Does the alternative splicing events mean all splicing regions, even for the same gene ? if that's the case, then yes, I am looking for something like that !